# SharePoint Framework Question - New

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Can we use SharePoint framework for SharePoint Online as well? or just for on prem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharePoint Framework works for SharePoint Online and also for on-premises (SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2 and SharePoint 2019).

**Reference**:

[Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

Citing from this page

> The SharePoint Framework works for SharePoint Online and also for on-premises (SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2 and SharePoint 2019).

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned SharePoint framework works for SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2 and SharePoint 2019).

But one thing to note here is that SPFX 1.4.1 is only supported for On premises. it means you can only create client side webparts using SPFx for on premises. You won't be able to create extension or library components which are available in latest version of SPFx.

Check official release notes at this [link](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki) to see available features as per release version